# I want write codes for counting numbers app. My app can count the numbers of pages. I want to add button for cleaning screen

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

```py
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        Screen.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        self.add_widget(layout)

        layout.add_widget(Label(text=self.name, font_size="150sp"))

        button = Button(text="Count",font_size='30sp')

        layout.add_widget(button)

        button.bind(on_press=self.add_screen)

    def add_screen(self, *args):

        n = len(self.manager.screen_names)

        screen = TestScreen(name="{}".format(n))

        self.manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.manager.current = screen.name 
        


# Create the screen manager

sm = ScreenManager()

sm.add_widget(TestScreen(name=''))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':

    TestApp().run()
```

I can't add button with a view to cleaning screen. I know this app not for counting. But i only need add button for cleaning numbers.

Comment: You just want clean screen (remove button/label), and to do this, you want to add clean button for all screens?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is or what exactly you want. Try to be more specific about what you want it to be.